When is "push-forward" a measurable function?
Let $n$ and $m$ be two positive integers. Let $\phi:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$ be a continuous function. Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb C$ be a continuous function. Define the "push-forward" function $\phi_\ast f :\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb C$ by
$$\phi_\ast f(y)=\sum_{x\in \phi^{-1}(\{y\})}f(x).$$
Question : Under which reasonable conditions is $\phi_\ast f$ a measurable function ? For example if we suppose that $\phi$ is a finite-to-one map, then is $\phi_\ast f$ measurable ?
I don't know if there are wild counterexamples. Any hint or reference would be highly appreciated.
